# Neural Network Written in Python is Extremely Slow

Tags: python, performance, numpy, neural-network

I coded a basic feedforward neural network with all pure python with the exception of numpy in order to better understand how neural networks work. It works, but the only problem is it is extremely slow, and I have no idea how to fix it. The neural network looks like this:

```
import numpy as np 

from digits import x_train

np.random.seed(0)

def leaky_relu(inputs):
    return np.maximum(0.1*inputs, inputs)

class Layer:
    def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_neurons):
        self.weights = 0.1*np.random.randn(n_inputs, n_neurons)
        self.biases = np.zeros((1, n_neurons))
        self.updated_weights = self.weights
        self.updated_biases = self.biases
        self.dc_dz = []

    def forward(self, inputs):
        self.output = leaky_relu(np.dot(inputs, self.weights) + 
self.biases[0] 


l1 = Layer(784, 8)
l2 = Layer(8, 128)
l3 = Layer(128, 128)
l4 = Layer(128, 64)
l5 = Layer(64, 10)

l1.forward(x_train[0].flatten())
l2.forward(l1.output)
l3.forward(l2.output)
l4.forward(l3.output)
l5.forward(l4.output)

layers = [l1, l2, l3, l4, l5]

def leaky_relu_derivative(output):
    if output > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0.1

def calculate_bias(output, actual=None, dc_dcn=None):
    if dc_dcn is None:
        return leaky_relu_derivative(output) * 2 * (output - actual)
    else:
        return leaky_relu_derivative(output) * dc_dcn

def calculate_weight(output, input, actual=None, dc_dcn=None):
    if dc_dcn is None:
        return input * leaky_relu_derivative(output) * 2 * (output - actual)
    else:
        return input * leaky_relu_derivative(output) * dc_dcn

def calculate_dc_dcn(weights, dc_dz):
    #find the derivative of the cost function in respect to the current node
    return np.sum(np.multiply(weights, dc_dz))

def train(learning_rate, actual):
    prev = None
    next = None
    x = len(layers) - 1

    while x != 0:
        layer = layers[x]
        next = layers[x-1]

        if x == len(layers) - 1:
            for i in range(len(layer.output)):
                #for every node in the layer
                new_bias = calculate_bias(layer.output[i], actual[i])
                layer.dc_dz.append(new_bias)
                layer.updated_biases[0][i] -= learning_rate * new_bias
                for j in range(len(next.output)):
                    #for every weight of the current node
                    new_weight = calculate_weight(layer.output[i], next.output[j], actual[i])
                    layer.updated_weights[j][i] -= learning_rate * new_weight
            prev = layer
        else:
            for i in range(len(layer.output)):
                #for every node in the layer
                dc_dcn = calculate_dc_dcn(prev.weights[i], prev.dc_dz[:(len(prev.output))])
                new_bias = calculate_bias(layer.output[i], dc_dcn)
                layer.dc_dz.append(new_bias)
                layer.updated_biases[0][i] -= learning_rate * new_bias
                for j in range(len(next.output)):
                    #for every weight of the current node
                    new_weight = calculate_weight(layer.output[i], next.output[j], dc_dcn)
                    layer.updated_weights[j][i] -= learning_rate * new_weight
            prev = layer
    
        for layer in layers:
            layer.weights = layer.updated_weights
            layer.biases = layer.updated_biases

        x -= 1
```

I'm assuming the code isn't very efficient and probably written poorly so any constructive criticism along with how to make it faster would help.

Comment: It looks like you have an indentation error (`train` function). Can you indent what is supposed to be contained in the function?

Comment: @Linny oh yeah right, missed that one  

Comment: Could you specify what the `digits` module is? Is it a published package or some local module?

Answer (score 1):

While I have no direct answer to your question, there is [scikit learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html), which is a python library using numpy exactly doing what you want. Downloading the package and inspecting the code for the appropriate functions to see what they do differently might be helpful.

Apart from that nested `for` loops are a usual suspect for slow code. Try to replace those loops with [matrix multiplications](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/312445/why-does-expressing-calculations-as-matrix-multiplications-make-them-faster) which compute faster on modern hardware.